# Meta curious badge bug

Tags: support

I am already meet the requirement for the curious badge still it is showing in list. **It is bug or something i missed?**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [**this answer**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267682/236518).

The condition which you need to meet to achieve this badge is :

> (total questions - negative questions - closed - early deleted)/total questions >= 0.5

I can see only 9 questions under your belt now. So based on that questions you should get this badge. However as you can see in the given answer, you may have some closed/deleted questions which are older than 60 days in your history, which may be preventing this.

So You are not alone, lot of awesome-heart people suffer the same. Best of luck.

**PS:** May be moderators can give you more details regarding the calculation.

Comment: Thanks for info.